# nftw different on BSD?

Tags: c, unix, posix, bsd, nftw

I'm trying to get all .c files in a directory tree using `nftw` with the following code:

```
static int gf(const char *path, const struct stat *st, int t, struct FTW *ftw) {
    if (t != FTW_F)
        return 0;
    if (strcmp(ext(path), ".c") == 0)
        addl(&files, dup(abspath(path)));
    return 0;
}

void getfiles(char *path) {
    nftw(path, gf, 255, FTW_PHYS);
}
```

It works on Linux and Solaris, but on PC-BSD it fails by simply not picking up any files. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you really used the name "dup" for strdup?  That seems like a disaster waiting to happen!  Does dup2 copy two strings?

Comment: I'm doing my own memory management for strings; dup is a function that basically does the same job as strdup except without the overhead of the general memory manager. But even if there was a bug in that function, it wouldn't account for the observed behavior, because the test I'm running basically only checks whether addl was ever called.

Comment: But dup is a terrible name, since that is the standard library function that duplicates a file descriptor.

Comment: To clarify, if nftw is trying to duplicate a file descriptor and it calls your dup instead of the normal dup, it will likely fail and cause problems.  (I don't think it is likely that this is the problem, but it is definitely a potential source of future problems.)

Comment: Doh! I'd entirely forgotten about that function. You're right of course, I'll change the name.

Comment: Are the functions `addl()`, `abspath()`, and `ext()` also yours (as well as `dup()`)?  What's the type of `files`? Have you tested them independently?  Did you get it to work when you changed the name of your `dup()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the return value of `nftw`? If it's `-1` and the `errno is` set to `EINVAL` it's quite likely that you're exceeding the value of `OPEN_MAX`. Try passing a smaller value as third parameter to `nftw` and ensure it's smaller than `OPEN_MAX`.